# Managing magento database through vagrant

Tags: magento-1.9, database

Is there a way to use phpmyadmin if my Magento installation is on vagrant box? Or any recommendations for other tools?

Using command line is horrible if you are working with large tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course, just download and chuck in phpmyadmin in your work directory or use adminer https://www.adminer.org/ which is a single file that will enable you graphical interface to your database. Now access it through url e.g. example.com/adminer.php and use your database credentials to log in

Comment: I tried adding phpmyadmin to my vagrant box via this guide, but it didn't work. https://blossomrose.wordpress.com/2016/04/07/install-phpmyadmin-in-vagrant-box/

Comment: Are you using any specific Vagrant box ?

Comment: Yes, it's a custom one and not publicly available. It was made just for one project that I am working on (didn't make it myself). It has Ubuntu 14.04 on it and it uses nginx, php5, mysql 5.5.

Comment: Ok, it depends on your environment sometimes setup can be different on varying envs. I'll advise following few different guides until it works.
Just a side note if you place adminer.php (not phpmyadmin) file in root of your project and access it through site url/adminer.php you'll be able to log into database, that's what I do on my docker containers.